# Unable to perform image searches

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, troubleshooting

I have been using Tor on a limited basis for about a years or so.  Since the latest Tor upgrade to 5.5.4, however, I have been unable to perform image searches. I look for images that I can use with a couple of blogs I write, so I use the image search feature of the browser.  I input my search terms in the search box, and when the results page is displayed, I click on "Images" to browse the results.  When I click on an image, however, instead of taking me to the web site associated with the image, Tor produces a new, blank Google search page.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you opening it in new tab? If so, the new identity may be generated and your search can be lost

Comment: No. I am simply clicking on the image to open the web site.

Comment: What image search page do you use?

Comment: I begin my searches using Disconnect, enter my search terms. When it brings up the results, I click on "Images" and scroll through the results.  When I click on an image that interests me, instead of bringing up the initial splash page where I can click the link to go to the web site, it takes me instead to a blank Google search page.